# @angular/cli@1.7.4 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli

I have a strange bug. I have an angular app that uses angularJS modules or angular 5 modules.

I compile my code using `@angular/cli@1.7.4` + `npm version 5.6.0` and if I run the cmd `ng build --prod --output-hashing none --aot false` I get no errors and the application runs well, but if I run the command `gulp predebug && ng build --app=app_debug --watch --preserve-symlinks` I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
    at Object../src/app/app.module.ts (app.module.ts:147)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 53b81b2588e9ef027265:54)
    at Object../src/main.ts (main.ts:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 53b81b2588e9ef027265:54)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 53b81b2588e9ef027265:54)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 53b81b2588e9ef027265:25)
    at main.bundle.js:1
```

Follows a extract of my code:

```
import angular from '@primavera/corejs/ng/angular';
....
angular.module('angular2', [
  angularresource,
  angularsanitize,
  angularanimate,
  uirouter,
  uibootstrap]);
```

Notes:

1. The error is lauch on browser console
2. If I downgrade the angular/cli version to 1.5.0 works fine runing the comand `gulp predebug && ng build --app=app_debug --watch --preserve-symlinks` but the `ng build --prod --output-hashing none --aot false` fails to run and throw some errors to the npm console.

I already see on [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/issues/81) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9729) that origin of the problem could be the version of the cli, but even downgrading to the version 1.6.8 is not working.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. For some reason, if I change the importation of  my lib from:

```
import angular from '@primavera/corejs/ng/angular';
```

to:

```
import * as angular from '@primavera/corejs/ng/angular';
```

the error no longer appears and everything works well.